# Change starring system in chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat

Here a proposal to a new starring system:

1. I understand that all of the SE devs are in the US and that they're culturally biased to voting being anonymous.
2. Starring is not voting: it's in a chat; it's not voting; it's starring...
3. Change the starring algorithm to anything else then what we've got today. (Really! Anything! It cannot get any worse!)

So far my feature request... **:-)**

Eliciting answers that contain such algorithms...

Comment: Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5298/367990

Answer (score 4):

My comment got too long to be a comment. A few things:

1. [The developers](http://stackexchange.com/about/team) aren't all in the US and anonymous voting is a global *requirement* of democracy to prevent corruption.
2. Starring *is* voting, but like with everything in chat, it's far more transitional than anything else we vote on.
3. (Most importantly) what's wrong with what we have?

I won't deny that some things could be better about chat, but overhauling how the stars work is pretty low down the list. They aren't supposed to be a critical feature of Chat. Mods and room owners can "pin" important messages.

If *how people are using them* is the real issue, perhaps that doesn't need developers, it needs a social conduct expectation. We get a lot of new users who aren't familiar with the system. If you see a deluge of inane stars, say something to the room about it (at the time it's happening).

Comment: When did you turn red?

Comment: [Grumble]Tired of seeing banter starred[Grumble][Grumble]Ok, OK, I'll wine and complain a bit more in the room itself...[bow][Shuffle out]  **;-)**